# Task Scheduler Batch not fully working

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have an issue with my batch script that's configured to run every 6 hours every day through Windows Task Scheduler. The batch does it's job if I run the Schedule or batch manually, but not when it's run automatically.

Here's how the batch looks like:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Arma 2 CO\instance_11_Chernarus"
cscript /nologo "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Batch Jobs\DayZ Epoch\timezone.vbs"  > newfile 2>> error.log
del config.cfg
ren newfile config.cfg
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 3 >NUL
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Arma 2 CO"
start "arma2" /min "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Arma 2 CO\Expansion\beta\arma2oaserver.exe" -port=2302 "-config=instance_11_Chernarus\config.cfg" "-cfg=instance_11_Chernarus\basic.cfg" "-profiles=instance_11_Chernarus" -name=instance_11_Chernarus "-mod=@DayZ_Epoch;@DayZ_Epoch_Server;"
cd C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\BEC\
start C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\BEC\bec.exe -f Config.cfg
```

Now, the batchs' job is to restart a Arma 2 OA Game server, and when I run the script manually, the server restarts well, although, when it's being run automatically, the server throws me an error with "No entry Cfg.worlds" and that's an error that something on this line has not been included in the server properly:

```
start "arma2" /min "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Arma 2 CO\Expansion\beta\arma2oaserver.exe" -port=2302 "-config=instance_11_Chernarus\config.cfg" "-cfg=instance_11_Chernarus\basic.cfg" "-profiles=instance_11_Chernarus" -name=instance_11_Chernarus "-mod=@DayZ_Epoch;@DayZ_Epoch_Server;"
```

Comment: if you have more volumes you should use `cd /d "X:\PATH....`

Comment: So if I add that to each cd, it would work? I'm not jumping between my drives though. I'm staying on the same drive all the time.

Comment: You probably don't want to be starting a server style application from a scheduled task as it will run with lower CPU, IO, and memory priorities (the first can be configured, but the other two cannot).

Answer (score 0):

The system account which task scheduler uses by default has no access to network resources - so if your server is on a network and you are not using credentials with enough access then that will be the reason.

Comment: I've set it up to execute under the same account I'm using (Administrator account). I just ticked in "Run with highest priviliges", will that do any difference? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I guess you will see if it helps or not.